# Count of line with exception

Tags: shell

I need help from anyone for my requirement.

Example i have a file with data like below,

```
2015/02/09 20:40:52.444|>=|E|X|50790506|6945| |||||||||||||||Uncaught Exception in SilentScope: dgDocument:ExecuteActionMDP: 0.013kdgDocument.cpp:5612: TraceLog message 8  

2015/02/09 20:40:52.444|>=|E|X|50790506|6945Uncaught Exception in SilentScope: dgDocument:UpdateQueryMDP: 0.013kdgDocument.cpp:1829: TraceLog message 10
2015/02/19 20:40:52.444|>=|E|X|50790506|6945Uncaught Exception in SilentScope: dgDocument:UpdateQueryMDP: 0.013kdgDocument.cpp:1829: TraceLog message 10
2015/02/29 20:40:52.444|>=|E|X|50790506|6945Uncaught Exception in SilentScope: dgDocument:UpdateQueryMDP: 0.013kdgDocument.cpp:1829: TraceLog message 10


2015/03/21 00:21:45.880|>>|A| |40370348|6510| |||||||||||||||assert failure: (auditsrc.cpp:2205). (false : AuditeeManager::AuditEventCache::getData: Unknownexception caught.  Rewinding all the way back to start of getData so that the auditor won't lose any audit events).auditsrc.cpp:1875: TraceLog message 3
2015/03/22 00:21:45.880|>>|A| |40370348|6510| |||||||||||||||assert failure: (auditsrc.cpp:2205). (false : AuditeeManager::AuditEventCache::getData: Unknownexception caught.  Rewinding all the way back to start of getData so that the auditor won't lose any audit events).auditsrc.cpp:1875: TraceLog message 3
```

Requirement:

Need script which will extract the line with word Exception with count as below (text after timestamp| with count),

```
>=|E|X|50790506|6945| |||||||||||||||Uncaught Exception in SilentScope: dgDocument:ExecuteActionMDP: 0.013 kdgDocument.cpp:5612: TraceLog message 8 ---1  

>=|E|X|50790506|6945Uncaught Exception in SilentScope: dgDocument:UpdateQueryMDP: 0.013 kdgDocument.cpp:1829: TraceLog message 10 -- 3  

>>|A| |40370348|6510| |||||||||||||||assert failure: (auditsrc.cpp:2205). (false : AuditeeManager::AuditEventCache::getData: Unknown exception caught.  Rewinding all the way back to start of getData so that the auditor won't lose any audit events).auditsrc.cpp:1875: TraceLog message 3 ---2
```

Please help me out to acheive this using unix shell script

Thanks a ton in advance.

#### Update

Used the code given and PFB the result on both old and new code,

```
$ sed -n 's/.*[^[:alpha:]]\([[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]]* *[eE]xception.*\)/\1/p' SystemOut.log| sort | uniq -c
51 IllegalStateException: SRVE0199E: OutputStream already obtained
$ sed -n -e 's/[[:alpha:]]* *[eE]xception/\n&/' -e 's/.*\n//p' SystemOut.log | sort | uniq -c
$
```

The second code didnt give me the count as first...

The actual entry is ,

```
SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet /viewers/cdz_adv/getImage.jsp in application AnalyticalReporting. Exception created : java.lang.IllegalStateException: SRVE0199E: OutputStream already obtained
```

So the result i am especting is below,

```
51 SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet /viewers/cdz_adv/getImage.jsp in application AnalyticalReporting. Exception created : java.lang.IllegalStateException: SRVE0199E: OutputStream already obtained
```

Previously i said one word before exception but now we need two words before exception..

Please help...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: In the first version of the question, we were supposed to include in the output everything after the date-time stamp.  In the second version, we were to include the line starting with the first word before the first occurrence of "exception" or "Exception".  In the third update to the question, the entry no longer has a date-time stamp at all and the output line has two words before the first occurrence of "exception.".  What is the new rule that you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
$ sed -n '/[eE]xception/ s/[^|]*|//p' file | sort | uniq -c
      2 >>|A| |40370348|6510| |||||||||||||||assert failure: (auditsrc.cpp:2205). (false : AuditeeManager::AuditEventCache::getData: Unknownexception caught.  Rewinding all the way back to start of getData so that the auditor won't lose any audit events).auditsrc.cpp:1875: TraceLog message 3
      1 >=|E|X|50790506|6945| |||||||||||||||Uncaught Exception in SilentScope: dgDocument:ExecuteActionMDP: 0.013kdgDocument.cpp:5612: TraceLog message 8  
      3 >=|E|X|50790506|6945Uncaught Exception in SilentScope: dgDocument:UpdateQueryMDP: 0.013kdgDocument.cpp:1829: TraceLog message 10
```

(The above differs from your desired output in that the count is first on the line rather than last.  If that is important to you, that can be changed.)

#### Variation

> Suppose i need to display from one word before Exception instead of
>   after timestamp, how can i do that??

```
$ grep -oiE '[[:alpha:]]* *exception.*' file | sort | uniq -c
      1 Uncaught Exception in SilentScope: dgDocument:ExecuteActionMDP: 0.013kdgDocument.cpp:5612: TraceLog message 8  
      3 Uncaught Exception in SilentScope: dgDocument:UpdateQueryMDP: 0.013kdgDocument.cpp:1829: TraceLog message 10
      2 Unknownexception caught.  Rewinding all the way back to start of getData so that the auditor won't lose any audit events).auditsrc.cpp:1875: TraceLog message 3
```

Or, using `sed`:

```
$ sed -n -e 's/[[:alpha:]]* *[eE]xception/\n&/' -e 's/.*\n//p' file | sort | uniq -c
      1 Uncaught Exception in SilentScope: dgDocument:ExecuteActionMDP: 0.013kdgDocument.cpp:5612: TraceLog message 8  
      3 Uncaught Exception in SilentScope: dgDocument:UpdateQueryMDP: 0.013kdgDocument.cpp:1829: TraceLog message 10
      2 Unknownexception caught.  Rewinding all the way back to start of getData so that the auditor won't lose any audit events).auditsrc.cpp:1875: TraceLog message 3
```

The above was tested on GNU sed but the code is intended to be BSD compatible as well.

#### AIX

Let's try some tests on the new file format:

```
$ cat SystemOut.log 
SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet /viewers/cdz_adv/getImage.jsp in application AnalyticalReporting. Exception created : java.lang.IllegalStateException: SRVE0199E: OutputStream already obtained
```

It appears that AIX sed does not support the use of `\n` as a newline character.  As a workaround, let's try:

```
sed -n -e 's/[[:alpha:]]* *[eE]xception/!&/' -e 's/.*!//p' SystemOut.log | sort | uniq -c
```

This uses an exclamation points, `!`, as a marker.  Since none of your sample log entries so far have had any exclamation points in them, this should work.

#### Yet Another Variation

As requested in the comments, this version returns not just the first word before `[Ee]xception` but the whole line:

```
$ cat SystemOut.log 
SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet /viewers/cdz_adv/getImage.jsp in application AnalyticalReporting. Exception created : java.lang.IllegalStateException: SRVE0199E: OutputStream already obtained
$ sed -n '/[eE]xception/p' SystemOut.log | sort | uniq -c
      1 SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet /viewers/cdz_adv/getImage.jsp in application AnalyticalReporting. Exception created : java.lang.IllegalStateException: SRVE0199E: OutputStream already obtained
```

Comment: @John -  I got the whole file entries while using both the codes you gave...displays whole file with Uncaught changed to nUncaught...

Comment: @Thangan That is helpful information.  Please try the code in the update.

Comment: Awesome, i can get the count and entries...right now getting entries from Uncaught.... can you help me to get from SRVE0068E: Uncaught...

Comment: can you please help me with the above?

Comment: Hi John..thanks for the update but we need only two/three words back because in actual file it starts with date due to that i am getting duplicate ( please see the section "Example i have a file with data like below" for the actual data)...please modify your previous code to pull two words before exception....thanks a lot and sorry to bug you...

Comment: ,i am not able to make it..pls help when you have minute :)

Comment: Hi John, Thanks you for your support...everything worked well :)